# Promise infinite callback

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('ok')
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

let bar = foo(); // line 1
bar.then(() => { // line 2
  bar = foo(); // line 3
})
```

Wondering why line 3 doesn't refresh line 2
causing infinite
1. promise resolve
2. re-instantiating `bar` back to 1.

If you'd actually want it to infinitely cycle as stated above, how would you change this code without writing a callback hell?

Comment: Assigning a new value to `bar` doesn't cause you to go back and re-execute `bar.then()`

Comment: a promise can by definition only resolve once. Also, the `then` method is on the original object value of `bar`, regardless whether you reassign something else to `bar` later. This is not really specific to promises, but how variable assignment works.

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can loop endlessly. To not block the browser completely, I have added a `setTimeout` so the promise only resolves after about half a second:

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('ok');
  // Lets give the browser some air to breathe...
  return new Promise(resolve => 
      setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 500)
  );
}

const loop = async () => {
    while (true) await foo();
};

loop();
```

Without `async` `await` syntax:

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('ok');
  // Lets give the browser some air to breathe...
  return new Promise(resolve => 
      setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 500)
  );
}

const loop = () => {
    foo().then(loop);
};

loop();
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer `foo().then(loop);` I wonder why it isn't `foo().then(loop());`?

Comment: Because `then` expects a (callback) function as argument. So you should not *execute* the function yourself. That is what the promise API will do when it finds the promise is settled, ... not you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('ok')
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

let bar = foo(); // line 1
bar.then((val) => { // line 2
   bar = foo() // line 3
})
```

First, we execute `foo()` here

```
let bar = foo(); // console.log('ok')
```

Then you do

```
bar.then((val) => { // after it
   bar = foo() // you again run this and get console.log('ok')
})
```

Then what? No one runs it again.

Want an infinite loop?

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('ok')
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

Promise.resolve().then(function resolver() {
    return foo()
    .then(() => console.log("ok"))
    .then(resolver);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function that and resolves a promise in every iteration

```js
const foo = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('ok');
    resolve()
  }, 1000)
})

const loop = (task) => {
  task().then(() => {
    loop(task)
  })
}

loop(foo)
```